# Universal app crashes on iPad simulator at each alternate time

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-simulator, universal

My app crashes on iPad simulator in alternate builds, crash then run then crash, etc.

```
objc[1116]: Class Protocol is implemented in both /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib and /Users/NGA24iMAC3/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/C0FFA7D7-7684-4854-B641-62BD11CFD226/Innovations.app/Innovations. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2011-02-09 11:53:01.446 Innovations[1116:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "PadLoginScreen" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01286be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x013db5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0123f628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0123f59a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x004a2b75 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 295
    5   UIKit                               0x004a0709 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x004a05e3 -[UIViewController view] + 56
    7   UIKit                               0x0049ea57 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    8   UIKit                               0x004af201 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    9   UIKit                               0x004ad831 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    10  UIKit                               0x004aeb4c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    11  UIKit                               0x004a9606 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    12  UIKit                               0x004b083e -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
    13  UIKit                               0x004a94a0 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    14  Innovations                         0x00006172 -[SplashScreenController switchView] + 303
    15  Foundation                          0x001887a5 __NSFireTimer + 125
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01267fe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01269594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x011c5cc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x011c5240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x011c5161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x01b52268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01b5232d GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x0040142e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  Innovations                         0x00002e70 main + 102
    25  Innovations                         0x00002e01 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

But all outlet set correctly in IB.Please help me.Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please type `WHERE` on your console just after your app crashes. Press `Enter` and see if any helping line number is received.

Comment: @Madhup,It shows the line where i am pushing the view then it say voew outlet not set.but next time it runs fine.

Comment: Can you also show that whole log ?

Comment: @Madhup,Now it is complete log.

Comment: so that means the issue is in the other view controller. place breakpoints on the methods that are been called at the time of initialization of that view controller. like `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @robin,viewDidLoad is not called when crashed.crash is view outlet is not set.but my outlet are set.

Comment: @Ishu i think that something is wrong with your connections in IB.I know you checked your IB but can you make your `.xib` file once again.

Comment: @robin,this now working.But i dont understand why this problem is there.i am doing same thing in new xib.

Comment: you probably didnt deleted the build directory in the project folder or reset the iphone simulator. something like that.

Comment: No this is not like that i delete a lot of times.this is any other thing.ok robin please edit your answer then i can accept that one.

Comment: @robin @ishu Boys, do chat in the chatting section :P ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ishu i think that something is wrong with your connections in IB.I know you checked your IB but can you make your .xib file once again.

Comment: Yes i can see this my view outlet is correctly set thats why it runs correctly also but it crashes in alternate time.

Comment: @Ishu i think you have used libobjc.A.dylib as global breakpoint, can you `debug - breakpoints on`. and when the app crashes you will get the line at which the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest cleaning your project. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Next, open your XIB file and verify that the view outlet of the "File's Owner" is connected to your view. Of not connect and it and save.

Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem in my Universal app .

I did something like this that solved my problem -

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)n bundle:(NSBundle *)b
{
    return [self init];
}


- (id)init
{



    BOOL iPad = NO;
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    iPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#endif


    if (iPad) 
    {
        // iPad specific code here
        NSLog(@"Device is iPad");
        [super initWithNibName:@"ContactUsViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];

    } else 
    {
        // iPhone/iPod specific code here
        NSLog(@"Device is iPhone");
        [super initWithNibName:@"ContactUsViewController" bundle:nil];

    }

    return self;
}
```

when you are adding/pushing viewController just call its init method and then push viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open our iPad xib in Interface Builder
2. Click on File's ownner
3. In the Inspector, go to the fourth tab (Identity)
4. Write as class identity the name of the class that is acting as view controller for that xib.
5. Ready to go!